# setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5") not working with thymeleaf-spring-4

Tags: java, html, spring, maven, thymeleaf

I have a simple HTML5 login page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <body>
       <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
           <fieldset style="text-align:center;">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
           </fieldset>
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

On my templateResolver configuration I set it to "LEGACYHTML5" like so:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(engine);
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

This was working great when loading thymeleaf-spring-3 on maven, but now I've changed it to thymeleaf-spring-4 and I get parsing errors:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="login", line 35 - column 39
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplateUsingPool(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:166)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.xmlsax.AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.parseTemplate(AbstractNonValidatingSAXTemplateParser.java:116)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
...
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</input>".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
...
```

To clarify, the first error points to the `autofocus` attribute on the input element. I have also tried setting the templateMode to "HTML5", with no results.

Did something change from thymeleaf-spring-3 to thymeleaf-spring-4? Am I missing something? Is there another mode I could use that I'm not aware of (the documentation for thymeleaf-spring-4 wasn't very clear)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5` to the `application.properties` file , instead of using the Java based configuration, resolved this problem.
This requires [NekoHTML](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.nekohtml/nekohtml) version 1.9.15 or higher in the classpath.

Comment: You could simply use spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5 if NekoHTML is not require

Comment: unfortunately NekoHTML isrequired in this case